# bash script redirect output and display on another terminal that is on another machine via ssh

Tags: bash

ok. i'm stumped.
i have two computers, call them machine1 and machine2. I want to execute a command on machine1, and pipe the output to machine2. this part is easy and I can already do this. what I am stumped on, is how to open a terminal on machine2 that displays the output of the terminal on machine one.

an example: i run a script at work that takes a lot of time. this script has a progress dialog built in to it, which displays the progress in the terminal on machine1. while this script is running, i leave my work office (location of machine1), drive home to my home office (machine2). I would like to see the output of the script in a terminal on machine2 when I get home.

right now i use the following workaround:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh user@machine2 'echo "" > file.txt; DISPLAY=:0.0 \
nohup conky -q -c /path/to/a/conkyrc \
> /dev/null 2> /dev/null < /dev/null &' \
#the conkyrc displays the last few lines of file.txt
echo "Hello world, or other commands" | ssh -q user@machine2 "sh -c 'cat >> file.txt'"
```

so, this runs a command on machine1, and pipes the output to a file.txt on machine 2, which is read and displayed by conky on the screen of machine2. when i get home, i see the status of the script i started running at work displayed in a conky panel.

this is functional - but I want to do better.

QUESTION 1:
how can I modify the above script so that the output goes BOTH to the file.txt on machine2 AND still gets outputted on machine1? i have tried using

```
tee -a - ????
```

where ???? is an ssh location. unfortunately, this doesn't work unless the ssh location is mounted on machine1, which I don't want to do.

QUESTION2: can i create a similar effect, by opening a terminal on machine2 via ssh from machine1, and displaying the output in BOTH the terminal on machine1 AND the terminal on machine2.
example: i use a variation of the script below to show a progress bar in the terminal on machine1. i would like to open a terminal on machine2, via ssh from machine1, and display the progress dialog from commands executed on machine1.

```
#!bin/bash
#A gauge Box example with dialog
(
c=10
while [ $c -ne 110 ]
do
    echo $c
    echo "###"
    echo "$c %"
    echo "###"
    ((c+=10))
    sleep 1
done
) |
dialog --title "A Test Gauge With dialog" --gauge "Please wait ...." 10 60 0
```

thanks in advance for anyone that can help. I am not a great programmer, just a simple minded mathematician.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `screen`

It's a fabulous `tty` emulator with many features!

Take a look at `man screen`

(A little like *remote desktop* or *VNC*, but in character mode, so very quick and I insist: with a **lot** of nice features)

On machine1:

```
screen -D -R
```

This will open a new `bash`.

on machine2:

```
ssh -t user@machine1 screen -x
```

And the pseudo `tty` userd for session on *machine1* is shared.

At any time, you could either close you window or disconnect from any of this two terminal by hitting escape sequence as `Control + A` followed by `d`.

At all, you could connect other console from elsewhere by typing `screen -x` or force disconnect others by typing `screen -D -R` instead of `screen -x`.

(care not to run `screen` from inside a screen session)